# What is timer_t at its base?

Tags: types, timer, posix-api

Gcc and `printf` says that `timer_t` is pointer (on my `linux`). But what is placed by this pointer, and is `NULL` a valid timer id?

Also, is it platform-specific thing, e. g. it is pointer on `linux`, int on `macOs`, sth. else on `BSD`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you talking about userspace or kernelspace? It makes a difference even on a single platform. Really it comes down to what the implementation of the functions, which SHOULD be considered as opaque.

The implementation of the functions uses `timer_t` might use an integer as an offset into an array of data structures, or dynamically allocates the backing timer data structures.

That opaque-ness of the timer functions means that NULL might be valid in some systems but not others.

If you look at the Single Unix Specification for `sys/types.h`, you'll see while it mentions `timer_t`, and says "All of the types are defined as arithmetic types of an appropriate length", but doesn't specify what exactly is stored inside the type (since a pointer is really just an integer that happens to be the address of somewhere else in memory).

Linux kernel headers (`int`):

```
include/linux/types.h:typedef __kernel_timer_t  timer_t;
include/uapi/asm-generic/posix_types.h:typedef int      __kernel_timer_t;
```

Linux glibc sources/headers (`void*` pointer):

```
time/bits/types/timer_t.h:typedef __timer_t timer_t;
bits/types.h:__STD_TYPE __TIMER_T_TYPE __timer_t;
sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86/bits/typesizes.h:#define __TIMER_T_TYPE     void *
sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/sparc/bits/typesizes.h:#define __TIMER_T_TYPE       void *
sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/s390/bits/typesizes.h:#define __TIMER_T_TYPE        void *
sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/generic/bits/typesizes.h:#define __TIMER_T_TYPE     void *
sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/alpha/bits/typesizes.h:#define __TIMER_T_TYPE       void *
sysdeps/nacl/bits/typesizes.h:#define __TIMER_T_TYPE        void *
sysdeps/mach/hurd/bits/typesizes.h:#define __TIMER_T_TYPE       __S32_TYPE
bits/typesizes.h:#define __TIMER_T_TYPE     void *
```

[Solaris headers (via GCC)](http://www.sde.cs.titech.ac.jp/~gondow/dwarf2-xml/HTML-rxref/app/gcc-3.3.2/lib/gcc-lib/sparc-sun-solaris2.8/3.3.2/include/sys/types.h.html#498) (`int`):

```
#ifndef _TIMER_T
#define _TIMER_T
typedef int timer_t;    /* timer identifier type */  <typedef:timer_t>
#endif  /* ifndef _TIMER_T */
```